# How to change the color of customtkinter entry when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am currently building an app where I have created 5 entry widgets in one row. There is a checkbox in each row and when that checkbox is marked or checked, however you want, all entries go green. Also the user can add as many rows as he likes. The problem is when checkboxes in other rows are checked, entries in those rows don't turn green. Does anyone have an idea how to make that work? Thank you in advance.

```
def checkbox_check():
       print(main_checkbox_var.get())
       if main_checkbox_var.get() == 1:
            for main in main_entries_list:
                main.config(fg_color="white")
```

#I have put all entry widgets in a list and the for loop should iterate and change the parameter

```
main_checkbox = ctk.CTkCheckBox(master=scrollable_frame_Main,text=None,hover_color="#176828",
fg_color="#37CB56",command=checkbox_check,variable=main_checkbox_var)
main_checkbox.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=0,sticky="w")
```

Comment: Use `main.configure(...)` instead of `main.config(...)`.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: *"Tried that. Doesn't work."* - What have you tried?  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: I have tried using main.configure(...) instead of main.config(...) and it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you create those entry widgets? If they are instances of `CTkEntry`, then `.configure(...)` should work. Once again, it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Sorry I am very new to stack overflow and I didn't realize that I can click on the link that you have provided. How can I provide the code that is used for creating those Entries. I cant paste it in the comment since it is too long,

Comment: You can edit your question.